# Reconnecting to a Mapped Drive after Server Restart from within PowerShell Script

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a PowerShell v1 script that connects to a remote server via a mapped drive and moves files back and forth the remote server is identified by drive number "M" and also by UNC path REMOTESERVER\DATA:

```
(M:) \\REMOTESERVER\DATA
```

When the remote server reboots, I think that I am screwed because now the mapped drive will be inaccessible by the script.

The issue is not when the mapped drive actually disappears, it is that after reboot, authentication is needed and Windows apparently will not remember that.

How is this situation handled programmatically from within a PowerShell script?

Is there a way to reconnect to the mapped drive by writing some PowerShell code?

Just curious how this is accomplished?

Comment: Are you sure that you're screwed?  Seems to me that the client should be unaware of the fact the server is rebooting, and should work just fine.

Comment: I never depend upon mapped drive letters in scripts - I always use UNC paths. Drive letters aren't necessarily persistent and may vary between users.

Comment: I should clarify: The issue is not when the mapped drive actually disappears, it is that after reboot, authentication is needed and Windows apparently will not remember that.

Comment: How is the script running? If the system where the script itself is executing doesn't reboot, no additional authentication should be required if you're working with domain accounts.

Comment: No domain accounts, unfortunately.  We have no domain server, so these would be local